# C# HtmlAgilityPack behaves differently when running project in Visual Studio debugger or when running a built executable

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrap a web site with HtmlAgilityPack library for C#. More specifically, I'm pulling data from a table which contains crypto-exchanges, it's rates and other data. The problem is: when I launch the project in Visual Studio, all the data is always pulled correctly and there are no errors, however, when I build the project and run it as an executable, one of the table columns is 50% of the time empty (I suppose the Xpath just returns an empty node).

What is more, I have spotted such behavior in another project of mine with HtmlAgilityPack. It is similar web scraping, but with another web site where i first need to log in. Each hour I need to re-login to get fresh cookies from the site, but every 10-12 hours the project fails as it can't find the specified html element in the login page. I launch it 1 time in visual studio, it works just alright and i re-launch the executable and it continues normal behavior for another 10-12 hours until it stumbles again.

Below is the code snippet for the first case:

```
//Getting the web page
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
htmlDoc = web.Load("https://www.bestchange.ru/bitcoin-to-bitcoin-bep20.html", proxies[p].ip, proxies[p].port, proxies[p].login, proxies[p].password);

// parse NAME
if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
    xpath = $"//body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr{i}/td[2]/div/div/div";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (bodyNode != null)
    {
        exchange = bodyNode.InnerHtml.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + exchange);
    }
}
//parse PRICE
//This is what gets screwed
if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
{
    xpath = $"//body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr{i}/td[3]/div[1]/text()";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (bodyNode != null)
    {
        Double.TryParse(bodyNode.InnerHtml, out price);
        Console.WriteLine("Price: " + price);
    }
}
```

So the price is what is usually pulled wrong (as 0).

I tried to run it on different OS - mac and windows, code it again on another platform, but the result is always the same.

Comment: Does the website return the same htmlcode when running in VS and as executable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cpt.oneeye I actually compared them and they are indeed different, which I wouldn't expect. Why can they be different then?

Comment: @YaroslavKolyada This probably happens on the server which is serving the html. Maybe there is another UserAgent or something else is different at clientside which the website on the server is checking. As a result it sends different html back.

Comment: @cpt.oneeye Thanks for the answer! Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @YaroslavKolyada I didn't really worked a lot with HtmlAgilityPack. You could try to make a local website. You call this website with your crawler in VS and in the executable. In your website you try to get some infos how the client looks like and if there are differences (maybe the useragent is different, or there are problems with keeping the login). Maybe there are settings you can define in HtmlAgilityPack so that it is more similar to the VS-Version.

Comment: @YaroslavKolyada Or you check if value is missing. If it does you make a new request until it works (you said it only happens in 50% of the times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem, it has nothing to do with HtmlAilityPack, instead it was a culture issue. Somehow my Double.TryParse Method was considering doubles only with "," instead of "." (and was outputting the same). I soled it by setting the default thread culture to "en-Us".